# Chart.js chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to declare a new chart using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), but the chart is not rendering.

I originally tried declaring it using:

```
new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

However, that code gave me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Pie is not a function

I tried changing the code to:

```
new Chart(ctx , {
    type: "pie",
    data: data,
});
```

This caused the error to disappear, yet the chart still doesn't render.

I've tried using different browsers and the same issue still occurs.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pv77779y/

Any help with getting the chart to render would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your complete code?. Or give us a fiddle link to check?

Comment: Updated with a fiddle link

Comment: take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/wprnvyd1/

Comment: Thanks, that's helped a lot!

Comment: This fiddle too => https://jsfiddle.net/pv77779y/4/

Comment: You seem to be missing some basic understanding of how chart.js is supposed to be set up. Like I don't see any `<canvas>` object, and you are not setting the data up correctly. I would suggesting looking at the [chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) for examples of how to properly set up a chart.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar issue wherein the chart.js documentation was not helpful. Then I noticed that the chart.min.js version should be the latest one. This day we use 2.5+ and the documentation is for that version.

So try replacing the file, and reloading your page (conforming to documents of chart.min.js 2.5+)

Comment: Same for me. Version was simply too old and none of the examples worked. For it to be this different would made me worried about an update breaking any usage of the charts with an older version.

Answer (score 0):

How you created your context? It should be

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
```

Comment: I have yes. Have now posted a jsfiddle link to the code

Comment: define a html canvas <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>